# WSL does not work after automatic update "WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070050"

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded the Windows Subsystem for Linux version of 20.04.4 LTS from the Windows store and it ran well at first.

Since the automatic update, each time I open the terminal, I get always the same message:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...  
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070050 
Error: 0x80070050 ?????
Press any key to continue...
```

Then it shuts down... I don't know how to fix it.
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: This is related to Windows hm looks like WSL itself has some issues. I am not really an expert on Windows, but is it possible to reinstall just WSL without losing your VM?

Comment: I tried with uninstall the Ubuntu ->disable the WSL fonction ->reboost the PC ->re-able the WSL ->reboost the PC ->reinstall the software but it doesn't work, same error always comes

Comment: That error code is a Windows error code.  It typically seems to get to installation issues with updates, and debugging that is a Windows task, not a Linux task, and that's needing a Windows forum, not Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I know this was closed, but I found an (albeit crappy) fix.

1) Stop WSL with `wsl --shutdown` in powershell or cmd
2) Open the run dialog (Win + R) and enter `%localappdata%\Packages\`
3) Find the folder starting with "CanonicalGroupLimited" and delete it (not permanently)
4) Start WSL again and let the update happen. Create a new user account.
5) Stop WSL again and restore the deleted folder from Recycle Bin, choosing to overwrite duplicate files

When you start WSL again you should be back in your original account with all of your original files.

Comment: @ThomasWard It turns out that this particular problem seems to actually be in Canonical's `ubuntu.exe`.  While it might be considered a "bug report", there are [several workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401852/1165986).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401830/wsl-not-working-after-update-from-microsoft-store answers this

Comment: @BrianWhite Thanks Brian.  I also asked Zanna to "re-close" this one as a duplicate of the other so that we point folks to the right place.  This one was asked first, I know, but was unfortunately closed, meaning I ended up answering on the second one (after I determined that this really *is* a Canonical problem, not a "Windows" problem.)  Personally, I'd encourage some upvotes on this question (as well as the other one).  It does appear a lot of folks are running into this.