# WSL not working after update from Microsoft store

Tags: 20.04, updates, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Version**
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586]

**WSL Version**
WSL 2

**Kernel Version**
5.10.16

**Distro Version**
Ubuntu20.04LTS

**Other Software**
Docker Desktop (Windows), version 4.6.1 (76265) Docker Engine v20.10.13

**Repro Steps**
I already had WSL installed from Microsoft Store few days and it was working fine. I got an update about the WSL from Microsoft Store and I updated it then it stopped working.

**Expected Behavior**
bash shell. Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed so it should operate normally.

**Actual Behavior**
Hello I had successfully installed WSL few days ago and everything was working fine. But after the I got an update regarding WSL from Microsoft Store I updated WSL and since then it is throwing this error. I also restarted the computer and checked to make sure my Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux are ON and I found out that both of these services were already ON. still I get the same error. May I please get any guidance on this one? as I have to use WSL for my educational purpose that would be really helpful thanks

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...<br>
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070050<br>
Error: 0x80070050 The file exists.

Press any key to continue...
```

Diagnostic Logs
No response

Answer (score 36):

A second possible answer based on the latest information.  I cannot test this personally since I am not having the issue.

Please backup (using the steps I mention in my previous answer) before trying this.

- `wsl --shutdown` (from PowerShell or CMD)
- In Windows, run the Registry Editor
- Find `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
- Find the key in there that has `DistributionName` of `Ubuntu20.04LTS`.  Change the `Ubuntu20.04LTS` to `Ubuntu-20.04`.

In theory, that may fix the problem by changing the distribution name back to what it should be.

Comment: This worked for me!  Thanks so much.  I did do the backup steps, but this change was all that was needed to get this working again, didn't need to reinstall at all

Comment: Worked for me too. Quick and easy!

Comment: @BrianWhite That's good to hear.  It's tough for me to post an answer that I can't necessarily test myself, so thank you for confirming that it works.

Comment: For anyone who found this helpful, note that I could *not* have possibly come up with it if [@Pat](https://askubuntu.com/users/1586158/pat) had not provided critical information in a comment on my previous answer.

Comment: Update: I don't know if it's related, but I can no longer hit Docker from inside this WSL instance. WSL integration is turned on in Docker, with Ubuntu-20.04 ticked Yes (was turned off after the rename). Yet inside WSL I only get "The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.". It worked before this incident, and although Ubuntu itself runs again, Docker does not.

Comment: @Phoenix Could certainly be related if Docker Desktop stored the "wrong" name somewhere.  Try this -- Turn "off" the option for that distro again, then fully reboot.  Then try re-enabling in Docker Desktop.  Hopefully this will force it to re-scan the names and pick up the right one.  If the "wrong one" is set to "on", however, it will probably still stick around.

Comment: @Phoenix Actually, before trying a reboot, turning Docker off for that distro and try just hitting "Refresh".

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Thanks

Comment: I can confirm this solves the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: This worked for me . Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thank you, this workaround really fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 11):

*Update:  This answer was my first attempt at the solution (which does work), and the "safe" way of doing it.  However, the "quick and easy" (but less "safe") registry edit that I posted as a [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401946/1165986) appears to be working for multiple users as well.*  This answer contains the background on the problem and *why* both of these techniques work for correcting it.

From reading through several Github issues (including, from the looks of it, one that you posted there), this appears to be a problem with the recent Store update of the Ubuntu app.  The `ubuntu.exe` or `ubuntu2004.exe` (*edit: I now believe this only happens with `ubuntu2004.exe`, but please let me know if you experience this on the `ubuntu.exe` version*) is broken after update.

The `ubuntu.exe` command really does two things -- It first checks to see if Ubuntu is installed in WSL.  If not, it extracts the Ubuntu rootfs and asks you to configure a username and password.  If it's already installed, it launches WSL using that distribution.

The problem seems to have actually started in the *previous* version of the "Ubuntu 20.04" app in the Microsoft Store.  The name of the distribution that is installed *should be* (historically), `Ubuntu-20.04`.  The previous version appears to have had a bug where this was renamed `Ubuntu2004.LTS` (thanks @Pat for pointing this out in the comments).

This would have caused a similar problem for *all* users that updated.  However, it seems Canonical quickly pushed a fix for the issue.

Unfortunately, if you installed during that window where the "bad version" was in the Store, then the fix *breaks* things for you, because now:

- `ubuntu2004.exe` is looking for a distribution named `Ubuntu-20.04`.
- It doesn't find it (because your version is incorrectly named `Ubuntu20.04LTS`), so it attempts to run the rootfs/configuration stage again.  But the WSL files are already extracted and configured, leading to the error.

There are several options:

- <strike>Personally, I'd just change any link to use the `wsl.exe` command instead of `ubuntu.exe` (or `ubuntu2004.exe`).  Assuming that Ubuntu is your default WSL distribution (found via `wsl -l -v`), then will have the same effect and just launch it.</strike> - *Edit -- It's worthwhile to actually fix this.*
- From the Github reports, you can truly fix the issue by unregistering the Ubuntu distribution.  Note that this is a **destructive** operation that will remove your existing Ubuntu distribution.

  Assuming that the distribution still runs, via the `wsl` command, it is possible to back it up before unregistering, then restore it afterwards.

  I would do this in two steps:

  - First, create a backup of the distribution via the `wsl --export` command.  Exit the distribution, then go to PowerShell and:

    ```
    wsl -l -v
    # Change "Ubuntu-20.04" in the next line to match the distribution name in use
    wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 ubuntu_backup.tar
    ```

    - Second, find the virtual drive for your Ubuntu WSL distribution.  Start in File Explorer with:

      ```
      %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages
      ```

      Then find the `CanonicalGroupLimited...Ubuntu` (the name may vary.

      Inside that, find `..\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`.  Copy that file to a safe location.
    - With two different backups in place, it's time to unregister Ubuntu from WSL.  Remember that this is a destructive operation:

      ```
      wsl -l -v
          # Change "Ubuntu-20.04" in the next line to match the distribution name in use
      wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
      ```
    - Rerun the `ubuntu2004.exe` or `ubuntu.exe` (either from the command-line or the Start menu)

      Ubuntu will again run its installation and initial configuration (and it should now work with the "bad" version unregistered).  While you can enter a username and password here, we're just going to throw this "installation" away anyway.
    - Exit the Ubuntu distribution
    - From PowerShell:

      ```
      wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04 # or Ubuntu
      ```
    - Copy the `ext4.vhdx` that you saved above back into `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\CanonicalGroup...Ubuntu...\LocalState` over the newly created one.

At that point, the `ubuntu.exe` or `ubuntu2004.exe` command should work once again (as well as from the Start menu).

Comment: wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu_backup.tar -> My storage is getting full, where can i find this? @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: @SivaGanesh You can place it on whatever drive you want:  For example, `wsl --export Ubuntu d:\wsl\ubuntu_backup.tar`.  By default it will create the `.tar` file in whatever directory you are in when you run it.

Comment: The name before the install was Ubuntu20.04LTS. After following the steps it changes to Ubuntu-20.04. Not sure if this might have something to do with the error.

Comment: @Pat That's a good observation.  The "problem" (naming issue) may have actually occurred in the previous update -- Then Canonical "fixed" it, but that fix is causing problems for anyone who installed from the "broken" version in the first place.

Comment: @Pat Make that a *great* observation.  Since folks are confirming that my second answer is working, it appears you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed it because I run Pycharm's interpreters and VSCode in WSL, since our code is meant to run under Linux. They completely broke since they use the name as a link.

Comment: I went with this method and it worked perfect, just for anyone that happens upon this question after me. Can't say anything about the other answer - but this one absolutely works.

Comment: I don't have a single file but a LocalState folder

Comment: @thistleknot You may be on WSL1 then.  Can you confirm with `wsl -l -v`?  If so, then this answer won't work for you, but the other one (registry edit) should.

Comment: I installed wsl2, but my distros are shown as wsl 1 (I have docker showing up as wsl 2)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you, your answer saved my installation 

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add if you use Docker you will most likely also need to update your container images.
You can run
`docker-compose pull`
Now you will also need to run the following which will update the container images.
`docker-compose up --detach`
`up` command automatically recreates container on image or configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code:
`wsl.exe -d Ubuntu20.04LTS` in your CMD or Powershell.
I ran it in the Terminal app

Comment: Just a heads-up that that will fix the *symptom*, but not really the *problem*.  You still won't be able to use the `ubuntu2004.exe` command (and the corresponding Start menu shortcut) to launch Ubuntu 20.04.  Also, I believe (but I can't confirm) that you won't be able to (at some point in the future) *uninstall* the Ubuntu 20.04 app from Windows if this error is still in place.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all these and still had problems. I finally resolved it by removing .wslconfig from c:\users\username\ directory. Then ran wsl --install (after unchecking Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows features) and it worked fine. I may have had to reboot my system after unchecking.