# [error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL

Tags: 18.04, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After adding a Python path to my environment variable I ran into an `[error 2147942402 (0x80070002)` when launching `ubuntu.exe` that's preventing me from launching Ubuntu in Windows terminal.

I don't know what happened. Is my environment variable messed up?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 via WSL2.

Comment: Can you launch via `wsl ~ -u root`?  If so, that may give you the avenue to back out the change, but I'm not sure that the environment variable is what's causing this problem.  Could be, but more likely just coincidence, with some other root cause.

Comment: Since there's a "Close Vote" here, let me take this opportunity to remind folks that Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL is an official Canonical/Ubuntu flavor that is still within the LTS support window, and is on-topic here.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds sure but in their defense:  this error is on the windows end not Ubuntu ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Probably, but we don't know for sure.  We've had questions [closed before](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1401482/timeline) because someone thought it was a Windows error, but after the same problem was [reposted by someone else](https://askubuntu.com/q/1401830/1165986), I found that this was purely a Canonical bug that they had introduced in an update and subsequent rollback.  That actually turned out to be one of the highest viewed questions on the site for the month.

Comment: I still love this quite relevant quote from Zanna [in Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17935/1165986) -- *"We should not close questions just because they smell ... Windowsy."*

Comment: @ovsama_nazoraya If you can't `wsl ~ -u root`, then please post the results of `wsl -l -v` (in an edit to your question) - Thanks!

Comment: Where should I run these commands please ? I tried Powershell and cmd and I got an error saying that wsl command isn't recognized.

Comment: @Ovsama_nazoraya Okay, that's definitely a problem, and could be why the "file not found" error code is coming up.  Try running the following from an administrative PowerShell -- `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" -online`.

Comment: I don't know how can I paste the output here because it's too long but anyways it shows among others that:  WSL2 is enabled / Restart required : possible.  I would like post a screenshot here but I don't really know how I can upload image here since I'm new to this forum.

Comment: This is where you can find full solution to this error [Error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching ‘ubuntu2204.exe’ fixed here ](https://www.prowebtips.com/error-2147942402-0x80070002-when-launching-ubuntu2204-exe/)

Answer (score 16):

Finally I managed to fix this error just by adding a path related to Windows Apps [ C:\Users\OS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps ] to my user environment variables instead of a Python path added mistakenly.

Hope this will help someone else in the future because I searched a lot and didn't find any fix to this error.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed.  Just a note that the original environment variable was probably `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.  Either one will work, of course.

Comment: Thanks, happened to me today, when trying to add adding `Git` to Path.

Comment: My WT installation required `C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH` to be located in the path environment

Comment: This worked like clockwork for me! Thanks! Just added the path to WindowsApps to my PATH variable :)

Answer (score 14):

### To fix this in Windows Terminal do the following:

1. **Access the Settings window:**
   [image]
2. **Select the wsl terminal profile (in this case Ubuntu):**
   [image]
3. **Click on Command line**
   [image]
4. **Change from ubuntu.exe (or something else depending on the operating system or ubuntu version) to wsl.exe and save the changes**
   [image]

Comment: As November 2023 this should be the correct answer! Thanks!

Comment: I had another Ubuntu option with a different path. If the above doesn't work then try `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`

Answer (score 2):

`error 2147942402` is a "File not Found" in Windows.

So I would assume ubuntu.exe is not found.

Are you sure of the exe name? IIRC it should be `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04`

Comment: I uninstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the App of that works fine but in windows terminal it doesn't work, it just keep throwing me the same error : [error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `ubuntu2004.exe'].  I also uninstalled Windows Terminal App and reinstalled it and tried again, nothing changed. I think something goes wrong with the Windows Terminal App because the Ubuntu 20.04 App works normally.

Comment: Not related to WSL or ubuntu, but: I found that this error was related to having unicode characters in the path. Just in case it helps future googlers who end up here.